# React native redirection Initial scene when I run add a product to the cart and open the modal

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with the adding a product and the opening of a modal in ReactNative.

The following button

```
<Button style={styles.errorButtonStyle} onPress={this.onAddToCartPress.bind(this, this.props.menuItem)}>
    IN CART
</ResetButton>
```

calls this function

```
onAddToCartPress(){
    textModal = 'Prodotto aggiunto'+"\n"+'al carrello';
    toCart = true;
    toAdd = true;
    this.props.openModal(textModal, toCart, toAdd, this.props.closeModal.bind(this), this.onGoToCart.bind(this));
    this.props.addToCart(this.props.menuItem, this.props.cartItems);
}
```

which in turn sets the variables that I need for my modal and perform 2 actions:

1. open the modal

   ```
   export const openModal = (modalText, isForCart, isAdd, onPressClose, onPressCart) => {
       return {
           type: OPEN_MODAL,
           modalText: modalText,
           isForCart: isForCart,
           isAdd: isAdd,
           onPressClose: onPressClose,
           onPressCart: onPressCart
       };
   };
   ```
2. add the product to the cart

   ```
   export const addToCart = ( item, cartItems ) => {
       return (dispatch) => {
           let total = 0.00;
           if(cartItems.length > 0){
               let find = false;
               for(var i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++){
                   if(cartItems[i].id === item.id){
                       total +=  (cartItems[i].qty+1) * cartItems[i].price;
                       find = true;
                   } else {
                       total +=  cartItems[i].qty * cartItems[i].price;
                   }
               }
               if(find){
                   addQtyToItemCart( dispatch, item, total);
               }else{
                   item.qty = 1;
                   total += item.qty*item.price;
                   addItemToCart( dispatch, item, total);
               }
           }else{
               total += item.price;
               item.qty = 1;
               addItemToCart( dispatch, item, total );
           }
       };
   };
   ```

   which in turn includes

   ```
   const addItemToCart = (dispatch, item, total) => {
       dispatch({
           type: ADD_TO_CART ,
           payload: item,
           total: total
       });
   };
   const addQtyToItemCart = (dispatch, item, total) => {
       dispatch({
           type: ADD_QTY_TO_ITEM_CART ,
           payload: item,
           total: total
       });
   };
   ```

**problem:** I cannot figure out why—when I click the button— `addToCart` is executed after which I get redirected to the initial 'Scene'. When I comment `addToCart` out, the modal opens and I stay on the right page.

Has anyone already happened?

Comment: Thanks kvantour, I tried to translate my request, I hope it is understandable.

Comment: I have edited your question to my best understanding of your original. Please review it and edit or revert if needed so that it still represents your original intent.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted to say. Thanks.

Comment: `openModal()` just returns an Object, where do u use it open or render the modal. Leaving that aside, `addToCart` returns a function, where do you use that function. Add few more bare-bones code from your source to find the issue.